# How do I download a file that is embedded in a web site?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

At this moment I can only download files that has this type of format:

> https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-8.1-415.jdbc2.jar

But how do I download files that aren't visible in the url file? 
For e.g Skype's url path:

> http://www.skype.com/sv/download-skype/skype-for-mac/downloading/

As you guys can see, there is no way I can download the file using

```
filePath.subString(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

So are there other ways to do this? I did find the file embedded in the page using FireBug which is

> http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-macosx.dmg

My question is, can I programmatically go through the page and get access to this file?

Here is the code which works fine for downloading

```
public static void fileDownload(String urlFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlFile);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpURLConnection.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpURLConnection.getContentLength();
        if (disposition != null) {
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10, disposition.length() - 1);
            }
        } else {
            fileName = urlFile.substring(urlFile.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, urlFile.length());
        }
        System.out.println("Content-type= " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Disposition= " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-length= " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("File name= " + fileName);
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = getDesiredPath() + File.separator + fileName;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
        int byteRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((byteRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied httpCode=" + responseCode);
    }

    httpURLConnection.disconnect();

}
```

It's my first time working with file management and this code is actually taken from [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url).

Comment: Are you asking how to follow redirection?

Comment: @RC. Yeah, I do apologize for my lack of terminologies. But that seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file if the file download link is embedded in the page.

Something like this in the web page html:

```
. . .

<a href="Skype.exe">Download Skype</a>

. . .
```

For downloading the page and scanning it for links you may use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

Code may look something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements anchors = doc.select("a");

// Untested code

for (var anchor of anchors) // ECMA 6 (i think)
{
    if (anchor.href.endsWith(".exe")
    {
        // if href is not full url i.e. not starting with http://  
        var downloadLink = url + anchor.href;
        // Download the file with the about url
    }
}
```